# Pharo: can I sort methods in a protocol manually instead of alphabetically?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I would like related methods inside a protocol to be grouped together instead of being sorted alphabetically.
The same could be said about the list of protocols themselves.

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot. However I think that would be a useful feature as it could be used to make easier for a programmer to understand the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just override the source code responsible for the methods selection and add some sorting.

```
MethodWidget>>loadMethods
    ^ (self model selectedCategories
        ifEmpty: [ self model methodsForCategory: self model allLabel ]
        ifNotEmpty: [ :cat | self model methodsForCategories: cat ])
        sorted: [ :a :b | a protocol <= b protocol ]
```

Personally I don't see much value in changing this directly in `SystemBrower` as you have million other ways to view the system (or just script it); in either case such changes are better discussed at Pharo's mailing list… this answer just provides *a* solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have lots of different browsers in Pharo. It is easy to add your own with the behaviour you want. You can just subclass the one closest to what you want to have, set the behaviour there, and set the default browser to be your own. Of course you'll need to maintain it then